# Batch Processing of Select query in clojure

Tags: clojure, batch-processing

I have a clojure application. It accepts a POST request with the following payload.

```
[
        {
            "key1": value1,
            "key2": value2,
            "key3": value3,
            "key4": value4
          },
          {
            "key1": value1,
            "key2": value2,
            "key3": value3,
            "key4": value4
          }
    ]
```

For each element of the array we make a SELECT call to DB using jdbc like so

```
(defn my-definition [db payload]
  (->> payload
       (map (fn [p]
              (if-let [da (my-db-call-method db)]
                (assoc da :key1 (:key1 p))
                {:key2 (:key2 p)
                :key3 (:key3 p)
                 })))))
```

**DB call**

```
(defn my-db-call-method [db json-params]
        (with-sql-handling "my-db-call-method"
           (jdbc/query db [my-query                 
                          (to long (:key1 json-params))
                          (to long (:key2 json-params))  

                    )))
```

my-query.txt would look something like below
`Select * from my_table where col_name1 = ? and col_name2 =?`
 Now, if 1 DB call takes 100 ms then 100 batch size would take 10 sec. This is too long. Is there a way to batch process the request in Clojure?  Please note that code is in working condition but taking a long time due to sequential processing. How can we parallel process this? Can we use any third-party library to achieve this?

Comment: that depends a bit on your database, but you could try `pmap` if you have some connection pool logic in `with-sql-handling` (usually you want one connection per thread)

Comment: I think your architecture is a bit smelly. For one, I think that you might be able to make only a single select statement for each request instead of N . Just make a single request and then process the returned db data in Clojure.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer The requirement changed completely and I never get to check your solution is the real environment. However, your solution did work on local environment and I did see improvement. Thank you